# Как собрать.NET Core приложение под linux-arm из Visual Studio?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, asp.net-core

У меня есть простенький проект на .NET Core 2, Собираю его под linux-arm из консоли таким образом:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm
```

Этот метод работает и собирает мне helloworld, который я затем могу запускать на Armbian.

Я не могу понять как сделать тоже самое из Visual Studio. Пробовал сделать это через публикации [image: Скриншот из программы, в списке рантаймов нет linux-arm], но на сколько я понимаю, там проект собирается через какое-то другое средство и в списке рантаймов нет linux-arm.